# Is it possible to remove window icon using QStyle in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qstyle

QStyle is a very flexible tool that helps customize your widgets. But how can I remove that icon using QStyle?

[image]

Comment: is that a MainWindow?

Comment: This can be dialog or window

Comment: You can remove the window decorations and use your own styling, the way Spotify does. But your users won't be happy with the theming opstions.

Comment: Have you looked into https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstyleoptiontitlebar.html ? Maybe this would help to achieve the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: You can use a empty or 1x1 pixel icon if you dont need it in system displaying.